# .datepicker() function works on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor, datepicker

I have a list of datepickers generated on runtime, each with an id, but all under the same class "datepicker"

```
<input class="datepicker" data-id="Adult" id="datepicker-0" Name="DateOfBirth0">
<input class="datepicker" data-id="Child" id="datepicker-1" Name="DateOfBirth1">
<input class="datepicker" data-id="Child" id="datepicker-2" Name="DateOfBirth2">
```

In javascript, I want to make adult's age between 13 and 90, and children's age between 2 and 12. So I am doing this:

```
 $(function () {
        $(".datepicker").click(function () {
            var aId = this.id.split('-');
            var refNum = aId[1];
            var dataId = $("#datepicker-" + refNum).attr('data-id');

            var minDate = "";
            var maxDate = "";
            if (dataId == 'Adult') {
                minDate = "-90Y";
                maxDate = "-13Y";
            }
            else if (dataId == 'Child') {
                minDate = "-12Y";
                maxDate = "-2Y";
            }

            $("#datepicker-" + refNum).datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                maxDate: maxDate,
                minDate: minDate
            });
        });
    });
```

So the weird thing that is happening, is that when the page loads, first time I click on the ".datepicker" input, nothing happens. Second time I click on the input, the datepicker calendar appears.

Any idea why?

Comment: because on first click only its registered as  datepicker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is working on second click because it is not taking the focus.
Check following fiddler created.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/0xr4jeba/
```

Hope this will help!!!

```
$("#datepicker-" + refNum).datepicker({
                              changeMonth: true,
                              changeYear: true,
                              maxDate: maxDate,
                              minDate: minDate
                          }).focus();
```

Comment: Thanks lot.Working Fine .

Comment: You have got to be Joking! It works. Also, if you're stringing a bunch of other functions on the datepicker, re-order them and make sure to call focus() first before the others.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".datepicker").click(function () {
                var aId = this.id.split('-');
                var refNum = aId[1];
                var dataId = $("#datepicker-" + refNum).attr('data-id');

                var minDate = "";
                var maxDate = "";
                if (dataId == 'Adult') {
                    minDate = "-90Y";
                    maxDate = "-13Y";
                }
                else if (dataId == 'Child') {
                    minDate = "-12Y";
                    maxDate = "-2Y";
                }

                $("#datepicker-" + refNum).datepicker({
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    maxDate: maxDate,
                    minDate: minDate
                });
            });

    });
```

This ensures that the document is loaded and event listners wire up before clicking

Comment: Check my solution above.